# how to get left value in pixels which has auto?

Tags: jquery

I have applied the following jquery and alerts the **auto**

```
var $divleft = $('#banner img').parent('div').css('left');
alert($divleft);
```

Is it possible to get the value of that div in pixels?

---

Ooops! sorry I was saying to width. It's left value of in auto and for which I want in pixel.

Comment: `var $divleft = $('#banner img').parent('div').position().left;` gets the elements distance from the left relative to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

with .css('left') you will just get the property of the stylesheet

try this

```
var $divleft = $('#banner img').parent('div').offset().left;
```

for inner width

```
var width = $(yourSelector).width();
```

for outer width

```
var width = $(yourSelector).outerWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var left = $('#id_name")[0].style.left;
```

It's worked for me.